# Print Object as List with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I retrieved an object and want it to be rendered in a HTML list like:

```
<ul>
 <li>Jon</li>
 <li>Doe</li>
 <li>Max</li>
 <li>Mustermann</li>
</ul>
```

The object I have looks like this:

```
Object {
  data: Object {
    allColleagues: [Object {
  name: "Jon"
}, Object {
  name: "Doe"
}, Object {
  name: "Max"
}, Object {
  name: "Mustermann"
}]
  }
}
```

For interest, I use the following function to get it:

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.responseType = 'json';
  xhr.open("POST", "https://api.graph.cool/simple/v1/XXXX");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
  xhr.onload = function () {
    testFunc();
    console.log(xhr.response);
  }
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify({query: "{ allColleagues { name } }"}));
```

Comment: What have you tried? What's the problem?

Comment: I did the following, but I don't get an output and don't know what to do else: var names = xhr.response; const listNames = names.map((name) =>
      <li key={name.id}>hi {name}</li>
);

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create list of li tag mapping each item in the allColleagues data.

```
import React, {
    Component,
} from 'react';

let data = {
    allColleagues: [
        {
            name: "Jon"
        },
        {
            name: "Doe"
        },
        {
            name: "Max"
        },
        {
            name: "Mustermann"
        }
    ]
}


class RenderDataAsList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                {
                    data.allColleagues.map((colleague, index) => {
                        return (
                            <li key={index} >
                                {colleague.name}
                            </li>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </ul>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add a key to the map function. Since you do not have any keys, at least add index number as key. `data.allColleagues.map((collegue, id) => <li key={id}>{colleague.name}</li>`

Comment: yep @illiteratewriter,  you are right, i've missed it, i will edit it just now.